# PHP MSSQL mssql_fetch_array - can't get results to echo

Tags: php, sql-server

I've successfully created a connection to an MSSQL database, executed a query and returned the results using mssql_num_rows. I'm able to get `$numRows` to echo and show "Rows Returned" on the page.

The columns in the table have these names: employeeName, prideSelect, prideComment, flagpoleSelect, flagpoleComment. All are nvarchar(50) or nvarchar(max)

What I'm not able to do is to echo any of the data in the table. I'm new to php/sql and I've tried searching for a solution with no luck. I'm not sure if it has to do with the database columns being set as nvarchar or not. Or if it is an error in my code. I've tried `mssql_fetch_array` and `mssql_fetch_row` to display the reults, but can't get either to work. Below is the code that I'm using:

```
<?php

//connects to Heros database

$conn = mssql_connect($host, $uid, $pwd) or die('Could not connect')
        or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $host");

$selected = mssql_select_db($db, $conn)
        or die("Couldn't open database $db");

echo "MSSQL Connection successful";

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM [Heros].[dbo].[tblHeros]');

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>";

//display the results 
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<li>" . $row["employeeName"] . $row["prideSelect"] . $row["prideComment"] . "</li>";
}

//close the connection
mssql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($result)` produce?

Comment: You might want to put those `<li>` elements inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>` tag.

Comment: @user1623347 - are those your actual database login details?

Comment: @andrewsi I removed those lines. SMH

Comment: Are you getting empty `<li>` lines, or no `<li>` lines at all? Empty lines = using the wrong references in `$row`. No lines at all = query produced no results.

Answer (score 1):

You want `mssql_fetch_assoc`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-assoc.php

Cheers

Comment: var_dump($result) shows this: resource(2) of type (mssql result)

Comment: No empty <li> lines are showing up. I'm going to try mssql_fetch_assoc

Comment: mssql_fetch_assoc worked if I write the query to only select one of the columns 'code' $query = mssql_query('SELECT prideSelect FROM [Heros].[dbo].[tblHeros]'); 'code'

If I change it to 'code' $query = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM [Heros].[dbo].[tblHeros]'); 'code' or 'code' $query = mssql_query('SELECT prideComment FROM [Heros].[dbo].[tblHeros]'); 'code' 
then I get this message: MSSQL Connection successful MSSQL error: Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier. fix: Cast ntext field to text?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: `$query = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM [Heros].[dbo].[tblHeros]');`

instead of: `$query = 'SELECT * FROM [Heros].[dbo].[tblHeros]';`